# Maximum achievable data rate (uplink) for a single user for a single OFDMA Resource Block in LTE-A

Tags: lte

I am reading a paper related to resource and power allocation and I come across the formula for *said* title. Now the question is I could not find any formula for the finding the data rate using SINR. The formula used in the paper is below

```
R = ln(1 + SINR_ijk);
```

where `SINR_x` is the `SINR` for a user *i* associated with cell *j* on a Resource block *k*

Where is this formula derived from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a form of Shannon's Theorem. See more at [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem)

[image]

As an aside, this does not take into consideration coding rate, modulation and many other factors that affect data rate.

(I would have made this a comment instead of an answer, but I do not have sufficient rep yet.)